# Is there a way in Nginx to remove a route specified in location from one domain and port and forward it to reverses proxy?

Tags: nginx, proxypass, path, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to connect **example.com:80** and **example.com:82** to a specific site through reverse proxy.

> **localhost/api/buy/ -> http://example.com:80/**
>
> **localhost/api/sell/ -> http://example.com:82/**

I set up the config file as below.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;



    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }


    location = /api/buy {
    return 302 /api/buy/;
    }

        location /api/buy/ {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header HOST $host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            proxy_pass http://example.com:80/;
            proxy_redirect off;
            }

    location = /api/sell {
    return 302 /api/sell/;
    }

        location /api/sell/ {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header HOST $host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            proxy_pass http://example.com:82/;
            proxy_redirect off;
            }

}
```

But If I connect /api/buy and /api/sell, I get a 404 not found error.

Below is the contents of the error.log file.

```
connect() failed (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://example.com/api/buy/", host: "localhost"
```

When using a different port, I confirmed that the setting works well.

I want to set it to the same port, but is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

best way is changed **proxy_pass http://example.com:80/** to
**proxy_pass http://example.com:80/api/buy/**

```
location = /api/buy {
return 302 /api/buy/;
}

    location /api/buy/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header HOST $host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_pass http://example.com:80/api/buy/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        }
```